# laravel user table and how to have eloquant table to get all managers

Tags: laravel

I would like to create a structure in my database with the 'user' table, it is a standard one and I would like a table to know the manager of the users (knowing they can have many managers) so something like this:

```
User
id
name
pass

Managers
id
manager_id (FK to User id)
user_id (FK to User id)
```

I know how to create the user table but I don't know about the model in Laravel to be able to use this Managers table. I am a bit confused on how it would be working and what type of many to many relationship I need to use.

I know how to address this in pure SQL but that would lose the point of using Laravel...

Thanks if you can help.

Comment: You need one pivot table for the many to many relationship

Comment: @Sagar the managers table acts the pivot table here

Comment: Yes, but my problem is with the fact that it is a pivot table between 2 times the same table so how do I use eloquent for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `belongsToMany` relation with `User` model

```
public function managers()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'managers', 'user_id', 'manager_id');
}
```

and if you want the opposite way that to get the employees of the manager

```
public function employees()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'managers', 'manager_id', 'user_id');
}
```